# osmdroid set bounds to edges of an image overlay in a mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid, bounding-box, overlays

I've made an app with an osmdroid mapview, the user is able to import a jpeg into the map as a groundoverlay, the image imported would be the floorplan of a building and would fill the mapview. Does anyone know how I would go about settings the scroll boundaries of the mapview to the edges of the groundoverlay so that the user cannot scroll outside of the groundoverlay/floorplan.
 any ideas on this would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the viewable area with `mapView.setScrollableAreaLimit(groundOverlayBoundingBox)`.

You may also need to limit the min zoom level (`MapView#setMinZoomLevel`).

Now, how to compute the `GroundOverlay` `BoundingBox` ?

- If your `GroundOverlay` has no bearing => look at `GroundOverlay#draw` source code, at `pEast` and `pSouthEast` computation. This should be a good starting point.

EDIT - with the maths:

```
GeoPoint pEast = position.destinationPoint(width, 90.0f);   
GeoPoint pSouthEast = pEast.destinationPoint(height, -180.0f);
int north = position.getLatitudeE6()*2 - pSouthEast.getLatitudeE6();
int west = position.getLongitudeE6()*2 - pEast.getLongitudeE6();
BoundingBoxE6 bb = new BoundingBoxE6(north, pEast.getLongitudeE6(),
  pSouthEast.getLatitudeE6(), west);
```

- If it has a bearing, ... tricky. There is a `GeometryMath#getBoundingBoxForRotatatedRectangle` in osmdroid which could help. But the scroll will not fit perfectly with the ground overlay edges.

Comment: I place my groundoverlay at a specific geopoint, I also resize the imported jpeg to fit the mapview exactly

Comment: I like this idea, i'm just having trouble getting the information for the area of the grouboverlay

Comment: I integrated this directly in GroundOverlay class, as a "getBoundingBox" method. The source code is already commited. It will be in the next version of the lib.